# What tool I should use to record down Ubuntu voice input and output

Tags: 20.04, audio-recording, zoom-meeting

I have a lot of online meetings for daily currently. I join these meetings with different tool, for example, ZOOM, or browser-based Google Hangout, or Microsoft team.

Is there a tool, can help me to record these meetings so I can review / reference after meetings finish? Because I don't have a good memory.

PS: I don't want to use ZOOM internal record function, besides, it is not common enough, I also need to use other tools for meetings

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested by recording the audio, consider using [Audacity in playback mode](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_linux.html).

Otherwise you probably need a screencast recording application like [one of these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts).

Comment: The OP wants to record both audio input and output. Will Audacity in playback mode record this? Because the description suggests that it will record output only.

Comment: You're right, I'm afraid there is no possibility to record both input and output at the same time with Audacity...